# Substitution of a solution on a set of functions

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I have been trying to solve an optical system using a matrix transfer method. The problem is that I want to see if an element of the matrix is constant. I used sympy to solve part of the matrix and I want to use these solutions to substitute them in another element of the matrix. I used sympy.subs but it seems that is not working. The code is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *

#all distances in mm
n1 = 1
n2 = 1.77
n = n1/n2
f1 = 200
f2 = 3.3
d = np.arange(1,300,10)
d1 = d[::-1]
d2 = f2+f1
d3 = 0.5*10**(-3)
z = symbols('z')

M2 = np.array([[1, 0], [-1/f1, 1]])
M3 = np.array([[1, d2], [0, 1]])
M4 = np.array([[1, 0], [-1/f2, 1]])
M5 = np.array([[1, d3], [0, 1]])
M6 = np.array([[1, 0], [0, n]])
M7 = np.array([[1, z], [0, 1]])

s = []
Mag =[]
for i in d1:
    M1 = np.array([[1, i], [0, 1]])
    M = np.dot(np.dot(np.dot(np.dot(M7,M6),np.dot(M5,M4)),np.dot(M3,M2)),M1)
    sol = solve(M[0,1])
    Mf = M[0,0]
    Mf = Mf.subs(z, sol)
    Mag.append(Mf)
    s.append(sol)
Mag


Output: [3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002,
 3.12250225675825e-17*z - 0.0165000000000002]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that will help:

1. solve for a specified variable. Since you want to replace `z` you should tell `solve` to solve for `z` as in `solve(M[0,1],z)`.
2. the output of `solve` will be a list of `z` values -- it looks like in your case there will be only one -- and `subs` expects a value, not a list, as the second arg: `Mf.subs(z, sol[0])`.

I do not use the directory, but there is an [optics directory](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/tree/master/sympy/physics/optics) in SymPy that might be of use.